# Why Google cloud falsely reports IN_USE_ADDRESSES limit exceeded upon VPN creation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpn, quota

I am unable to create a VPN connection because of the following error:

[image: From google.cloud]
This occurs even though the ONLY(?) google-based IP address I am required to enter already exists (created in "external IP Addresses") but is not in use.

These are my quotas:

[image]

Why is it not able to create my VPN connection, when I have plenty of quotas left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a VPN Connection apparently requires 3 available Addresses. I asked for an increased quota, and was able to create a VPN connection after recieving those.